# How do I upload a django project to github?

Tags: django, git, github, repository

THis is likely the dumbest question of all time on stack overflow... but I have spent close to an hour attempting this, with no luck, and am considering signing up to BitBucket.

1) Dragging and dropping into github, does not upload entire folder, but 5 out of about 30 .py files, and does not include any of the html, css etc... and does not keep any heirarchal structure as it only includes .py files

2) Command line: having `git commit` my folder, I try to `git push origin` and am met with this error:

---

*git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.*

*Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists.*

---

I have no idea what this means...

Comment: I presume you've run `git remote add origin git@github.com:[user]/[repo].git` for attempt 2? That error is an authentication error. You can check whether you have ssh (public key) authentication set up, and read more here https://github.com/settings/keys

Comment: it seems like a problem with your public key. Search on google and sort that. You can also clone your directory and then add files in there and then commit and push it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: I recommend going through the Github tutorials: [Getting started with Git and GitHub](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/getting-started-with-git-and-github)

Answer (score 0):

Did you use 'git init' to initialize the repo? What do you get from `git remote - v`?

**edit**

This atlassian doc migth help:
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a repo on github? 
You will need to:

- **Add** changed files
- **Commit** your changes
- **Push** to the remote repo

https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github